# Is there functionality similar to DefaultResponseErrorHandler for RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

A library that I maintain within my company provides a custom implementation of `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` that we assign via a `RestTemplateCustomizer`. This implementation looks at the actual http status code of the response and translates it.

Essentially our class overrides

```java
@Override
protected void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response, HttpStatus statusToReturn) throws IOException {
  super.handleError(response, someOtherStatusThatIsComputedInternally);
}
```

We simply pass in a different status code and Spring takes care of creating the appropriate `HttpClientErrorException`/`HttpServerErrorException`.

I'm trying to replicate this functionality in `WebClient` using an `ExchangeFilterFunction` (& inject via a `WebClientCustomizer`) but I'm not quite sure how to get at it, since `ClientResponse.statusCode()` is already set and can't be overridden, nor do I seem to have access to be able to override the creation of the `WebClientResponseException`.

Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what I needed to do using the built-in `ClientResponseWrapper` that Spring provides.

In my `ExchangeFilterFunction` I do this:

```java
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {
    return next.exchange(request).flatMap(this::handleAnyErrors);
}

private Mono<ClientResponse> handleAnyErrors(ClientResponse response) {
    HttpStatus actualHttpStatus = response.statusCode();
    HttpStatus statusToReturn = getActualStatusCodeWeWantToReturn();

    return Mono.just((actualHttpStatus != statusToReturn) ? new ClientResponseStatusCodeWrapper(response, statusToReturn) : response);
}

private static class ClientResponseStatusCodeWrapper extends ClientResponseWrapper {
    private final HttpStatus httpStatus;

    private ClientResponseStatusCodeWrapper(ClientResponse delegate, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        super(delegate);
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpStatus statusCode() {
        return this.httpStatus;
    }
}
```